# Problem with memory leaks

Tags: iphone, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

Sorry, having difficulty formattin code to appear correct here???

I am trying to understand the readings I get from running instruments 
on my app which are telling me I am leaking memory. 
There are a number, quite a few in fact, that get reported from inside 
the Foundation, AVFoundation CoreGraphics etc that I assume I have no 
control over and so should ignore such as:

Malloc 32 bytes: 96 bytes,  AVFoundation,  prepareToRecordQueue

or 
Malloc 128 bytes: 128 bytes, CoreGraphics, open_handle_to_dylib_path

Am I correct in assuming these are something the system will resolve?

But then there are leaks that are reported that I believe I am 
responsible for, such as:

This call reports against this line leaks 2.31KB

[self createAVAudioRecorder:frameAudioFile];

Immediately followed by this:

```
-(NSError*) createAVAudioRecorder: (NSString *)fileName {     

    // flush recorder to start afresh 
    [audioRecorder release]; 
    audioRecorder = nil; 

    // delete existing file to ensure we have clean start 
    [self deleteFile: fileName]; 

    VariableStore *singleton = [VariableStore sharedInstance]; 

    // get full path to target file to create 
    NSString *destinationString = [singleton.docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent: fileName]; 

    NSURL *destinationURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: destinationString]; 

    // configure the recording settings 
    NSMutableDictionary *recordSettings = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:6];       //******  LEAKING 384 BYTES 

    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM] forKey: AVFormatIDKey];   //***** LEAKING 32 BYTES 

    float sampleRate = 44100.0; 
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: sampleRate] forKey: AVSampleRateKey];   //***** LEAKING 48 BYTES 

    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]  forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey]; 

    int bitDepth = 16; 
    [recordSettings setObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt:bitDepth] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];   //***** LEAKING 48 BYTES 

    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey]; 

    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool: NO]forKey:AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey]; 

    NSError *recorderSetupError = nil; 

    // create the new recorder with target file 
    audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL: destinationURL settings: recordSettings error: &recorderSetupError];       //***** LEAKING 1.31KB 

    [recordSettings release]; 

    recordSettings = nil; 

    // check for erros 

    if (recorderSetupError) { 

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Can't record" message: [recorderSetupError localizedDescription] delegate: nil cancelButtonTitle: @"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil]; 

            [alert show]; 
            [alert release]; 

            alert = nil; 
            return recorderSetupError; 
    } 

    [audioRecorder prepareToRecord];  //***** LEAKING 512 BYTES 

    audioRecorder.delegate = self; 

    return recorderSetupError; 
}
```

I do not understand why there is a leak as I release audioRecorder at 
the start and set to nil and I release recordSettings and set to nil? 
Can anyone enlighten me please? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try running your app with instruments on a device. There are a few things with AVFoundation that leak on the simulator, but do not on real hardware!

but, on second thought, audioRecorder is never released. Maybe try either releasing it
at the end of the method, or perhaps using autorelease?